# How to calculate Follow set of a production rule that has only ONE symbol on the right side

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, grammar

So i have this grammar :

```
S -> (D)
D -> EF
E -> a|b|S
F -> *D | +D | ε
```

First of all, books solution uses the P -> pBq , First(q) - {ε} is subset of FOLLOW(B) for the rule D -> EF but that rule has only 2 symbols do we assume ε infront of E (ε being the p in pBq)?

And secondly i can't understand how to calculate Follow(E).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is computer science rather than programming. I suggest cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3):

`FOLLOW(E)` consists of every terminal symbol which can immediately follow `E` in some derivation step. That's the precise definition; it's not very complicated.

For a simple grammar, you should be able to figure out all the FOLLOW sets just be looking at the grammar and applying a little bit of common sense. It would probably be a good idea to do that, since it will give you a better idea of how the algorithm works.

As a side note, it's maybe worth mentioning that ε is not a thing. Or at least, it's not a grammar symbol. It's one of several conventions used to make the empty sequence visible, just like 0 is a way to make nothing visible. Sometimes that's useful, but it's important to not let it confuse you. (Abuse of notation is endemic in mathematics, which can be frustrating.)

So, what can follow `E`? `E` only appears in one place on the right-hand sdie of that grammar, in the production `D → E F`. So clearly any symbol which be the first symbol of `F` must be in `FOLLOW(E)`. The symbols which could be at the start of `F` are `+` and `*`, since as mentioned, `ε` is not a grammar symbol. (Many definitions of `FIRST` allow `ε` to be a member of that set, along with any actual terminal symbol. That's an example of the abuse of notation I was talking about in the previous paragraph, since it makes it look like `ε` is a terminal symbol. But it isn't. It's nothing.)

`F` is what we call a "nullable" non-terminal, because it can derive the empty sequence (which was written as `ε` so that you can see it). In other words, it's possible for `F` to disappear completely in a derivation step. And if it does disappear, then `E` might be at the end of the production `D → E F`. If `E` is at the end of `D`, then it can be followed by anything which could follow `D`, which includes `)`. `D` can also appear at the end of a derivation of `F`, which means that `F` could be followed by anything which could follow `F`, a tautology which adds no information whatsoever.

So it's easy to see that `FOLLOW(F) = {*, +, )}`, and you can use that to check your understanding of any algorithm to compute follow sets.

Now, I don't know what book you are referring to (and it would have been courteous to mention that in your original question; sources should always be correctly cited). But the book I happen to have in front of me --the Dragon Book-- has a pretty similar algorithm. The Dragon book uses a simple convention for writing statements like that. Probably your book does, too, but it might not be the same convention. You should check what it says and make sure that you typed the copied statement correctly, respecting whatever formatting used to indicate what the symbols stand for.

In the Dragon book, some of the conventions include:

- Lower case characters at the start of the alphabet. –`a`, `b`, `c`,…– are terminals (as well as actual symbols like `*` and `+`).
- Upper case characters at the start of the alphabet. –`A`, `B`, `C`,…– are non-terminals.
- `S` is the start symbol.
- Upper case characters at the end of the alphabet. –`X`, `Y`, `Z`– stand for arbitrary grammar symbols (either terminals or non-terminals).
- `$` is the marker used to indicate the end of the input.
- Lower-case Greek letters –`α`, `β`, `γ`,…– are possibly-empty strings of grammar symbols.
  The phrase "possibly empty" is very important, so I'm repeating it.

With that convention, they write the rules for computing the FOLLOW set:

1. Place `$` in `FOLLOW(S)`.
2. For every production `A → αBβ`, copy everything from `FIRST(&beta)` except `ε` into `FOLLOW(B)`.
3. If there is a production `A → αB` or a production `A → αBβ` where `FIRST(β)` contains `ε`, place everything in `FOLLOW(A)` into `FOLLOW(B)`.
   As mentioned above, `α` is a *possibly-empty* string of grammar symbols. So it might not be visible.
4. Keep doing steps 2 and 3 until no new symbols are added to any follow set.

I'm pretty sure that the algorithm in your book differs only in notation conventions.

Comment: That was helpful the example with F disappearing. I studied some more and understood it, it just confused me why the book used the A → αBβ rule for D -> EF since there's only 2 symbols on the right side but some pages later it added D -> εEF so if i understand correctly, you can put ε infront of stuff like D -> EF so as to get the A → αBβ ?

The book is from my university and there's no english version of it. It specifically states "From the rule Α -> αΒβ in D -> EF, First(F) - ε into Follow(E)

Comment: ε is not a thing. It's nothing. It's an empty sequence. α is not a symbol, either. It's a possibly-empty sequence of symbols. A possibly-empty sequence is possibly empty. Nothing is a surprisingly hard concept. And yet, it must be mastered. :-)

Comment: Yes i know that "ε" is nothing and it's there just to "show" me that the current symbol is the empty sequence. 

Doesn't D -> EF fall under the A -> αΒ category? so Follow(D) into Follow(F). HOW did the book use the First rule (Α -> αBβ) for D -> EF , did it take α as the empty sequence so like (D -> εEF) so i can use αΒβ? If yes, how do i know when i can take α = ε?

Comment: All that text is saying is that there is an  `E` somewhere in the right-hand side. Anywhere. Then α  is what is before and β is what is afterwards. There is no "how does it know"; it's just away of naming the prefix and suffix. If the RHS contains an `E` then the rule applies. (If it contains two `E`s then it applies twice, in either order, with different definitions of α and β.)